# Vue + Jest global config carrying over into spec files

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm using VueJS and Jest for unit testing my components.

I'm also using the Bootstrap Vue library for styling. I need to use this plugin in my Jest tests in order to remove some console warnings about unknown plugins.

I have created a setup file as so:

```
import { createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(BootstrapVue)
```

And configured Jest to use this before every test.

```
setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/tests/unit/setup']
```

However, to remove the warnings from the console, I need to use the `localVue` instance when mounting the component:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
      localVue,
      propsData: { value: 'someVal }
    })
```

However there is no way that I can see to get the `localVue` instance created in the `setup.js` into the test spec files.

If I do this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
```

It works fine, but this is bad as we should not be using the Global Vue instance in Jest tests.

**Is there a way to do what I want to do, or am I going to have to construct the Bootstrap Vue plugins (and others as they come along...) into every single test file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to assign the `localVue` variable as a global variable in your `setupFiles`. This would allow you access `localVue` variable in every test, like so:

```
import { createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

global.localVue = createLocalVue()

global.localVue.use(BootstrapVue)
```

Then use it like this in your test:

```
const localVue = global.localVue

const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
  localVue,
  propsData: { value: 'someVal' }
})
```

Comment: Excellent! This works. I've offered a slight edit to get it working. I could not use global.localVue in the config, but if I created a constant first that works.